# How to call the same api multiple times in Express Route?

Tags: loops, express, asynchronous, router, waterfall

I'm working on a Node app with Express. I'm chaining several http calls to data api's, each dependent on the previous req's responses.

It's all working except the last call. The last call needs to happen multiple times before the page should render.

Searching has turned up excellent examples of how to chain, but not make a call to the same API (or HTTP GET, data endpoint, etc.) with different params each time.

I'm trying to do something like this: [Using a generator to call an API multiple times and only resolve when all requests are finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248806/using-a-generator-to-call-an-api-multiple-times-and-only-resolve-when-all-reques)

```
var getJSON = (options, fn) => {
    .....
}

router.route("/")
    .get((req, res) => {
        var idArray = [];
        var results = [];
        getJSON({
            .... send params here, (result) => {

            //add response to results array
            results.push(result);

            //create var for data nodes containing needed id params for next call
            let group = result.groupsList;

            //get id key from each group, save to idArray
            for(i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
                idArray.push(groups[I].groupId);
            }

            //use id keys for params of next api call
            dataCallback(idArray);

        });  

        function dataCallback(myArray){
            // number of ID's in myArray determine how many times this API call must be made
            myArray.forEach(element => {
                getJSON({
                    .... send params here, (result) => {
                    results.push(result);
                }); 
            // put render in callback so it will render when resolved
            }, myRender());
        };

        function myRender() {
            res.render("index", { data: results, section: 'home'});
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned the problem with the above code.

1. You can call functions that are outside of the express route, but you can't have them inside the route.
2. You can't chain multiple data-dependent calls, not in the route.

Anything inside **route.get** or **route.post** should be about the data, paths, renders, etc.

This means either using an async library (which I found useless when trying to build a page from multiple data sources, with data dependent on the previous response), or having an additional js file that you call (from your web page) to get, handle and model your data like here: [Using a generator to call an API multiple times and only resolve when all requests are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248806/using-a-generator-to-call-an-api-multiple-times-and-only-resolve-when-all-reques) You could also potentially put it in your app or index file, before the routes.

(It wasn't obvious to me where that code would go, at first. I tried putting it inside my router.post. Even though the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router) says "Methods", it didn't click for me that routes were methods. I hadn't really done more than very basic routes before, and never looked under the hood.)

I ended up going with a third option. I broke up the various API calls in my screen so that they are only called when the user clicks on something that will need more data, like an accordion or tab switch.

I used an **XMLHttpRequest()** from my web page to call my own front-end Node server, which then calls the third party API, then the front-end Node server responds with a render of my pug file using the data the API provided. I get html back for my screen to append.

In page:

```
callFEroutetoapi(_postdata, _route, function (_newdata){
                    putData(_newdata);
                });

function putData(tData){
            var _html = tData;
            var _target = document.getElementById('c-playersTab');
            applyHTML(_target, _html);
        }

function callFEroutetoapi(data, path, fn){
    //url is express route
    var url = path;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    console.log('data coming into xhr request: ', data);

    //xhr methods must be in this strange order or they don't run
    xhr.onload = function(oEvent) {
        if(xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
            //if success then send to callback function
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                fn(xhr.response);
                // ]console.log('server responded: ', xhr.response);
                }
            else {
                console.log("Something Died");
                console.log('xhr status: ', xhr.status);
            }
        }                
    }
    xhr.onerror = function (){console.log('There was an error.', xhr.status);}
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

It adds an extra layer, but was necessary to show the latest, frequently changing data. It's also reusable which is better for a multiscreen web app. If there were fewer views (completely different screens and co-dependent datasets), a more centralized model.js file mentioned above would work better.